# Woocommerce hides cart_totals when using cart and checkout on same page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my cart page I updated it to include the two short codes:

`[woocommerce_cart]` – shows the cart page

`[woocommerce_checkout]` – shows the checkout page

By default the cart page is only populated with `[woocommerce_cart]` and it will show the cart, coupon code area, and cart totals. When I add the `[woocommerce_checkout]` it removes the cart totals box.

Does anyone know a work around for this? Or know of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce hides the cart totals by default when the checkout is also present on the same page. This is because it gives duplicate information that might be confusing for your customer, since the checkout also displays subtotal, total and shipping information.

You could bring the cart totals back with a snippet like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'woocommerce_show_cart_totals', 10 );
function woocommerce_show_cart_totals() {
    wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-totals.php' );
}
```

But changing the shipping method for instance wouldn't work as the shipping method option of the checkout would overwrite again what you have selected in the cart totals.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! 

Lucky my business is service based so there is no shipping to worry about.

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was of use to you.